# Google Sheets Charts values are not showing correctly/properly

Tags: charts

Could you please help show the values of Google Sheets Charts correctly/properly without using Google Apps Script, here is the print screens for details:
[Print screen # 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B4NR.png)
[Print screen # 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpjIw.png)